# Faster way to use radio buttons functionality without using radio buttons?

Tags: html, radio-button, liquid

I have a web page that loads in 14 images as selectable icons as radio buttons. Right now those buttons work where selecting one deselects another, which is my desired functionality.

Problem is that after clicking the desired image it takes (comparatively) a long time for that image to be "checked". Is there a faster structure for mutually exclusive large amounts of selectable buttons?

Here is my code below for clarification.

The action of clicking on one of these images and them become the exclusively checked image is like 6-700ms which feels ridiculous

```
<div class="image-gallery" align="center">
    <p align="center" style="font-size: 25px;">Now lets choose a team photo.</p>
    <div>
    {% assign upperLimit = photoCount%}
    {% for i in (1..upperLimit)%}
        <!--All the photos in the folder as clickable buttons-->
        <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="{{i}}" name="item" id="radio{{i}}">
            <label class="label_item" for="radio{{i}}"> <img src="/images/teams-pictures/{{i}}.jpg" class="img-selector"> </label>
    {%- endfor -%}
    </div>
    <div>
    <button class="button" style="padding: 15px 100%" onclick="next()">Next</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: this kind of thing is easily solved by the use of sprites

Comment: Radio buttons are the right way to go here. They are natively available and usable by users with disabilities. In terms of performance any alternative would be less good. Your question should rather be why it takes so long for your browser to change the buttons’ state. Do you have any JavaScript which binds on events there?

Comment: I believe that if you tried to create a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you would notice that it’s quite performant. The issue might also be connected to your browser and add-ons that you have installed. Is the issue reproducible on other devices?

Comment: @Andy The speed is consistently slow across devices once deployed on aws as well, additionally the only js that lives on that page is the next() function which just passes the number of the increment selected into the url for the next page. Thanks for the bit about it being best option for all users though I will keep it regardless of time issues.

Comment: What is the size and weight of your images?

Comment: @Andy yup thats it, using icons speeds up the proc quite a bit, is there some sort of caching going on with radio buttons? I was using decently hi-rez images with css shrinking them and as I kept selecting the proc got faster and faster. With icons it just started fast.

Comment: There is no caching, but if you offer 20 images with several Megabytes each, it’s clear that your browser might struggle. Try to provide the images in the size they are presented (maybe taking into account screen resolution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is not the radio buttons, but in JavaScript code that is triggered when you click, or the size of the images.

If I reproduce your case with actual images and 20 options, there is no perceivable delay between clicking an image and the radio button’s status change.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      upperLimit: 20
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <fieldset class="image-gallery" align="center">
    <legend align="center" style="font-size: 25px;">Now lets choose a team photo.</legend>
    <div>
      <p v-for="i in upperLimit">
        <!--All the photos in the folder as clickable buttons-->
        <input type="radio" class="radio_item" :value="i" name="item" :id="'radio' + i">
        <label class="label_item" :for="'radio' + i"> <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" class="img-selector" alt="Provide some helpful alt text for the option, please"> </label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```